# Cannot find module 'core-js/fn/array/values' in react native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

Hi I have just started working on `react-native` platform, followed this tutorial https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html I am getting this error.

```
E:\React Programming\AwesomeProject>react-native run-android
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'core-js/fn/array/values'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\React Programming\AwesomeProject\node_modules\reac
t-native\packager\babelRegisterOnly.js:11:27)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)

E:\React Programming\AwesomeProject>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove a reference to `core-js/fn/array/values`, probably you have a

```js
require('core-js/fn/array/values')
```

somewhere up in your code.

Remove that line.